# HOW TO: Basic HTML form to email and/or CSV file to post on local server (without server side script)

Tags: javascript, html, csv

I am looking to use an existing (basic)HTML form, that posts an eMail, to post as a CSV file to a drive on the server. can anyone tell me if this can be done without a Web Server? JavaScript would be okay since that is able to run in the browser and all users have access to post to the specified drive. This form has multiple fields and checkboxes.

Comment: The mail actions would be needed to be performed on the server.

Comment: You mean some kind of `<form action="mailto:…">` that will (try to) open the user's email client?

Comment: this already has the mailto: command  I am looking to do both send an email and save it as a CSV file on a server drive.

Answer (score -1):

Without a web server available, it seems rather hard (I'm tempted to say "almost impossible") to get the data to the server at all using JavaScript.

Comment: I have checked in other forums  as well. It looks like JavaScript will not be able to write without a web server. I will have to abandon the idea that needed to post a copy in the folder. I currently have a  html form that allows the user to post back with a email. I was just looking for more functionality that is all. Thanks for your help.